# Copy multiple selected rows from datagridview to textboxes

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a datagridview named PTable which shows a table from database. I also have a button that functions to copy the data from selected rows to the textboxes I have.

This code that I have right now copies two selected rows from the datagridview but when I only select one row or when I select more than 2 rows, it says that "Index was out of range"

What should happen is that it should copy any number of rows and not only 2 rows

```
private void button11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            productid.Text = PTable.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value + string.Empty;
            productname.Text = PTable.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value + string.Empty;
            unitprice.Text = PTable.SelectedRows[0].Cells[4].Value + string.Empty;
            productid2.Text = PTable.SelectedRows[1].Cells[0].Value + string.Empty;
            productname2.Text = PTable.SelectedRows[1].Cells[1].Value + string.Empty;
            unitprice2.Text = PTable.SelectedRows[1].Cells[4].Value + string.Empty;

    }
```

Comment: the `+ string.Empty` is not needed. Delete them. How many productidx productnamex unitpricex textboxes You have? Put them into a list

Comment: First change the SelectionMode of DataGridView to FullRowSelect. Otherwise users will likely select cells and not rows and the code would not work

Comment: @ntohl Okay. I will delete the string.Empty. I have 3 rows on the datagridview but there would be more when a new product is added. I have 5 textboxes.

Comment: Also use code for NULL checking.

Comment: @codetoshare It is already in FullRowSelect

Answer (score 0):

If a user have not selected two rows, your index 1 (PTable.SelectedRows[1]) is not valid, because the item is not there.
Before you can run this code, you have to check, if the user selected two rows:

```
if (PTable.SelectedRows.Count == 2)
{
  //Your code ...
}
else
{
  //Not two rows selected
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**First**, make sure **SelectionMode** of DataGridView to **FullRowSelect**(Hope you have done it already)

**Second**, Use **foreach** or any looping logic to go through each selected rows.

**Third**,  It's always better to write modular code. Write a validation method which returns TRUE or FALSE based on selection of the grid rows.
Now based on returned value you need to continue writing your business logic.

**Fourth**, Make sure to use **NULL** checks

So let's start by re-factoring the code.

```
  private void button11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      If(IsRowOrCellSelected())
      {
           //loop through selected rows and pick your values.
      }       
  }
```

I am just writing sample, make sure PTable is accessible.

```
  private boolean IsRowOrCellSelected()
  {
    if (PTable.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
    {
        DataGridViewRow currentRow = PTable.SelectedRows[0];
        if (currentRow.Cells.Count > 0) 
        {      
            bool rowIsEmpty = true;    

            foreach(DataGridViewCell cell in currentRow.Cells)    
            {
               if(cell.Value != null) 
               { 
                  rowIsEmpty = false;
                  break;
               }    
            }
       }
      if(rowIsEmpty)
           return false;
      else
          return true;
   }
```

Code can be still improved.

Answer (score 0):

To work with varying number of selected rows I suggest the following.

My approach is:

There may be more than 5 rows, that You have to display. First create 3 panels for the TextBoxes. I have named the one for the productids as *here*. Generate the textboxes from code, this way it's easier to maintain more than 5 selected rows:

```
// This code goes to the constructor of the class. Not in the button click
List<TextBox> productids = new List<TextBox>();
List<TextBox> productnames = new List<TextBox>();
List<TextBox> unitprices = new List<TextBox>();
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    productids.Add(new TextBox { Top = i * 32 });
    productnames.Add(new TextBox { Top = i * 32 });
    unitprices.Add(new TextBox { Top = i * 32 });
    here.Controls.Add(productids[i]);
    here2.Controls.Add(productnames[i]);
    here3.Controls.Add(unitprices[i]);
}
```

Than You can in the button click set the value for each selected row:

```
// This code goes to the button click
// first empty the Textboxes:
foreach (TextBox productid in productids)
{
    productid.Text = string.Empty;
}
foreach (TextBox productname in productnames)
{
    productname.Text = string.Empty;
}
foreach (TextBox unitprice in unitprices)
{
    unitprice.Text = string.Empty;
}

for (int i = 0; i < PTable.SelectedRows.Count; i++)
{
    productids[i].Text = PTable.SelectedRows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    productnames[i].Text = PTable.SelectedRows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
    // or better... Name the columns
    // unitprices[i].Text = PTable.SelectedRows[i].Cells["unitPrices"].Value.ToString();
    unitprices[i].Text = PTable.SelectedRows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
}
```